# Past tense of "to wing"?

Tags: past-tense

Is there a past tense of the verb "to wing," meaning to make up on the fly?

Inspired by a [blog post of Wil Wheaton](http://wilwheaton.typepad.com/wwdnbackup/2011/03/soup-black-bean-hot.html), quoted partially below.

> "Is it from a recipe, or are you
>   winging it?"
>
> "I've made so many different recipes
>   from so many different places, I just
>   looked through the pantry and
>   refrigerator and wung it."
>
> We looked at each other. "Wung it?" I
>   said. "I think I mean I am winging it.
>   What's the past-tense of winging it?
>   Wang it? Winged it?"
>
> "I don't know, but it's not 'wung
>   it,'" she said. I couldn't argue with
>   her.

Comment: "Wang" it :) ... priceless. Reminded me of Numberwang immediately.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"I winged it" is correct.

The phrase comes from "theatrical slang sense of an actor learning his lines in the wings before going onstage, or else not learning them at all and being fed by a prompter in the wings" http://on.oceg.org/hRqPUt

Comment: Not much doubt on that one at the present time. But *winged* is under pressure from many other words (*clung*, *flung*, *rung*, *stung*, etc.), so I expect *wung* has occured repeatedly in the past - facetiously and or through genuine ignorance. It may even become the standard form eventually.

Comment: @Fumble: It also has the advantage of being familiar to the ear (at least mine) from the [bird hunting sense](http://books.google.com/books?id=yaY-AAAAcAAJ&dq=%22winged%20it%22&pg=PA361#v=onepage&q=%22winged%20it%22&f=false) of the phrase, _to shoot in the wing_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There are other examples of "-inged", including _dinged_, _pinged_, _kinged_.

Answer (score 3):

"wung it" was relatively common colloquial usage when I was growing up in NW England. "winged it" in this context sounds wrong, even if technically correct.

"winged it" meaning "hit in the wing" (when talking about birds or aeroplanes) was generally not changed to "wung it".

Comment: I have also heard "winged it" to refer to hitting something in or with a wing. But "wung it" is a pretty major exception.