# Animalisms... What other terms derive from parts of an animal, like 'wing it', or 'hoof it'?

Tags: phrases, verbs, animals

The question " [Past tense of "to wing"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18355/past-tense-of-to-wing) " got me thinking about terms we use in the English language that derive from ***parts of an animal***, especially verbs or verb phrases, like 'wing it' or 'hoof it'.

There are many noun and adjective phrases that use animal parts, like 'on the horns of a dilemma', so I'm more curious about verbs and verb phrases, but all entries are welcome.

(-1 to anyone who proffers 'udder despair'!)

Comment: Pretty much anything an animal does? Root, fly, caw, screech, scamper, molt. I guess I don't understand what qualifications you are using.

Comment: Not what an animal does that a human can mimic, I'm looking for animal parts (nouns), 'wing', 'hoof', 'feather', etc., that are used as verbs (or other parts of speech) to describe what humans do.

Comment: Ah, okay. Are these better: _Feather_, _claw_, _tail_ (including _hightail_)?

Comment: @MrHen:  Yes, those are all great examples (although one might argue that 'claw' is an action that animals do that humans mimic.)

Comment: Udder despair, udder despair, udder despair. Now try to downvote this comment thrice. I'll wait. :P

Answer (score 3):

Some of these are pushing the definition, I'm sure, but...
You can:

- hightail it out of here.

  beef something up (or have a beef with someone).

  nose around.

  feather your nest.

  shank a ball.

  paw someone.

  go into hock.

  ham it up.

  keep abreast of something.

Answer (score 1):

A detective may tail a suspect.